# How to remove row from Different JTables with Single Remove Button

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Tabbed Layout in my application
 Please see this Image

[image: Tabbed Layout]

So as you can see in the above Image I've 2 Tables in 2-different Tabs in first tab (SALON STOCK tab)
i want to remove the selected row
what did is : removebutton's actionPerformed Method

```
        int row_num =jTable4.getSelectedRow();
    try{dtm_stock.removeRow(row_num);} 
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please select a Product");
    }
```

this works fine for the current tab(SALON TAB)
but how to implement same for the other Tab (Stock for Sale).

Further Details :

I have 2-table in the 2-diff tabs and bothe have 2-different TableModel (Default)
at initialization the data is set to null 
after that  the Data is retrieved from database and set to the corresponding TableModel.
now there is  a remove button which will remove the selected row from table

i want to remove the selected row from tables irrespective of any Tab

CODE : initialization

```
                jTable4 = new javax.swing.JTable();
                dtm_stock = new DefaultTableModel(new Object [][] {
        {null,null, null, null},
        {null,null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "ID","NAME", "PRICE", "QUANTITY"
    });
    jTable4.setModel(dtm_stock
    );
```

ADDING DATA :

```
//-----ADD STOCK TO THE STOCK TABLE --------------//

    try {

    ResultSet r7 = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from stock");
        while(r7.next()){
            dtm_stock.insertRow(dtm_stock.getRowCount(),new Object[]{r7.getString("id"),r7.getString("p_name"),r7.getString("price"),r7.getString("qty")});
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.toString());
    }
```

if i'm adding the same TableModel to the other Table then the data goes to that table and the current goes blank:

this seems to have did the trick :`

```
int selectedIndex = jTabbedPane2.getSelectedIndex();

    if(selectedIndex == 0 ){
        int row_num =stock_table.getSelectedRow();
    try{
        dtm_stock.removeRow(row_num);

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException/*|SQLException*/ e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please select a Product");
    }
    }//if

    if(selectedIndex == 1){
        int row_num =sale_Stock_table.getSelectedRow();
    try{
        dtm_sale_stock.removeRow(row_num);

    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException/*|SQLException*/ e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please select a Product");
    }
    }
```

from here :
[enter link description here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jtabbedpane/get-set-selected-tab-in-jtabbedpane/)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The two tables should share a common table model; if not, the two table models should share a common data source.

Comment: @trashgod - if they share same model how can they have different data, please explain .

Comment: If the two tables share a common table model, use @camickr's [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20860235/230513). If the two table models differ, they should share a common data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand corectly you can put some flag which will hold value for current visible tab and use if statment to remove row from correct Model. On the other hand better solution would be creating some kind of controller. The controller would store active tab, and would have removeRow method. Switching tab would trigger event so controller would know from which tab delete row.

Answer (score 1):

> if they share same model how can they have different data, please explain

You can control which columns to display in the view (JTable).

Look at the `removeColumn(...)` method of JTable. It removes a column from the view. However the data is still in the TableModel.

Comment: your idea is also right but, the problem is the query to set data in table model is different for every table so it seams little bit complicated to me  .